# single query two opposite group by

Tags: sql

I'm trying to generate report based off of SQL Queries. I need to generate one report with `Source = "Web"` and other without `Source <> "Web"`. I've read multiple posts on this but none of them gave me the answer. Query below.

```
SELECT
  content_provider,
  provider_asset_id,
  device_id,
  carrier,
  T.profile_id,
  phonenumber,
  dma,
  CAST( asset_play_duration as decimal(15, 3) ) AS asset_play_duration,
  series_title,
  episode_title,
  source,
  vsession_id AS session_id,
  event_day
FROM
  (SELECT
    device_id,
    program_asset_id,
    vsession_id,
    source,
    vsession_start_ts,
    batchtime,
    vsession_end_ts,
    IF ( studio = '', network_tag, studio ) AS content_provider,
    provider_asset_id,
    carrier,
    profile_id,
    phonenumber,
    series_title,
    episode_title,
    content_type,
    dma,
    asset_play_duration,
    source,
    event_day,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY device_id, program_asset_id, vsession_id, vsession_start_ts ORDER BY batchtime DESC) AS rank
  FROM ? ) T
LEFT JOIN ? tp
ON T.profile_id = tp.profile_id
WHERE tp.profile_id IS NULL
AND T.rank = 1
**AND T.source <> "Web"**
AND T.event_day BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

One report should be with above condition (`T.Source <>"web"`) and other should be without the filter (`T.Source = "Web"`). I tried Union and Inner join, and both of them did not work. Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: When did mySQL start supporting window functions?  (Question Tagged as *mySQL*  pretty sure they don't work there... so what RDBMS is this?)

Comment: Why dont you use UNION ALL?

Comment: show the two  separated working query  .. and explain the result you need

Comment: Also are you trying to pass in the table name as a variable?

Comment: Since the columns are not same, im not using union all @Teja

Comment: Yes. I'm passing as a variable @xQbert

Comment: the only difference between both the queries is T.Source = "Web" and T.Source <> "Web"
Rest is all same @scaisEdge

Comment: @pruthvi  could but the query you provide is not clear and is not functioning so . i repeat my previous comment : show the two separated working query .. and explain the result you need

Comment: @scaisEdge Ok. I'm unable to send complete query in a single comment. Also, I'm ranking it as 1 so that top record of that particular column is selected from the subquery.

Comment: @pruthvi  . try update your question ..

Comment: post some sample input and output... if u dont have same columns then make the names look similar and then do union all

Comment: sure. let me do that. @scaisEdge@Teja

Answer (score 0):

Pass yet another variable for whether you want to select "Web" or not, filled accordingly with 'YES' or 'NO'. Then:

```
AND ((? = 'YES' AND T.source = "Web") OR T.source <> "Web")
```

This assumes there *is* a column named `"Web"` (which you could call `Web` without quotes anyway). If `Web` is supposed to be a string, on the other hand, you'd use single quotes: `'Web'`.

Comment: I was passing table name above in the "?" and "Yes"  is like an argument here. I'm not sure if that works, but ill try !

Comment: I was surprised that you can pass a tabe name as a parameter. You may be right that the combination of both doesn't work. I don't know. It may make a difference whether you pass `YES` or `'YES'`.

Comment: you can pass as parameter @Thorsten Kettner